# How do I build model to explain variable yield rates from a lot of low variable data points?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, modeling, model, proportion

I have data that looks like the below. I would like to create a model that could answer the question: "If I have a data point with distance x and y people signed up, how many should I expect to check in?" (subject to all the usual hedges like not extrapolating or being too confident in the results, of course).

```
Signed Up   Checked In  Yield Rate  Distance (km)
274 171 62.41%  0
241 44  18.26%  475.9156416
132 22  16.67%  342.732219
123 53  43.09%  457.3099693
116 20  17.24%  833.4106358
41  20  48.78%  51.19124239
1   0   0.00%   2833.297793
1   0   0.00%   388.5309437
1   0   0.00%   1069.432695
1   1   100.00% 929.646838
1   0   0.00%   1103.6347
```

Note that yield rate is just (Checked In)/(Signed Up). I tried a basic linear correlation but for pretty obvious reasons, that won't work. What should I do? I've heard of pretty much all the big technologies (R, Python, TensorFlow) but I have very little experience in this space. I'm open to learning though!

Sorry about the poor tagging: I'm so lost with this problem that I'm not even sure what type of problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: From your data, it looks like you want to predict [Yield] from [Signed Up] and [Distance].  You'll want to use a Logistic Regression model to do that, rather than linear regression.

Comment: I'm confused to your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong but logistics regression requires categorical variables - I don't have those

Comment: If you want to give the _proportion_ of sign-ups that actually check in, you might want to use something similar to [this approach](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89999/how-to-replicate-statas-robust-binomial-glm-for-proportion-data-in-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with plotting your data, obtaining:

[image]

The size of the plotting symbols are proportional to the square root of number signed up.  We can safely disregard the smallest points, as they corespond to a sample size of 1. Apart from this, there is a nice falling tendency with distance. A logistic regression model could be used:

```
 mod1 <-  glm( cbind(x, N-x) ~ dist, family=binomial, data=dat)
 summary(mod1)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(x, N - x) ~ dist, family = binomial, data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-4.3429  -0.7503  -0.3305   1.8544   3.9497  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.3005630  0.1093824   2.748    0.006 ** 
dist        -0.0028817  0.0002891  -9.969   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 170.235  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  54.917  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 89.177

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The deviance here is so large so overdispersion is indicated, so you should maybe replace the `binomial` family with `quasibinomial`.  If your real data set is much larger, you could maybe represent dist with a spline function.

For brevity, I replaced the names in your data table with

```
 names(dat)
[1] "N"    "x"    "perc" "dist"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! What tool did you use to make this?

Comment: Everything was done in R https://www.r-project.org/