# Regression with bounded dependent variable

Tags: regression, causality, bounds

I'm using interrupted time series analysis to estimate the impact of an intervention in the same group. However, my target variable is a satisfaction index that goes from -1 to 1.

How can I model a dependent variable that is bounded between -1 and 1?

The distribution of the dependent variable looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could rescale to [0, 1] and use logistic regression?

Comment: Please clarify the structure of your data. Do you have a big N, small T panel or  just a single time series?

Comment: Beta regression is also an option

Comment: Call this variable $Y$' then $(Y + 1)/2 =: y$ is as @Scriddie advises within $[0, 1]$ and is fit for logistic regression. More at e.g. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X0800800212

Answer (score 1):

You could rescale to $[0,1]$ and then use Beta Regression ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_regression)) which is designed for response data that lies between $[0,1]$.
Also, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16936/299841) to a similar question which talks in a little more detail about the pros and cons of simply using logistic regression for this.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I interpret the coefficients afterwards? Do I need to scale back? For example, the interruption coefficient (based on a binary variable on whether there was interruption or not) is -0.2133 — does this mean that the index decreases by 0.213 with the intervention? Or do I have to scale the -0.213?

Comment: Also, how can I perform diagnostic checks on the beta regression? Two of my coefficients (time since intervention and time*intervention) are not significant

Comment: Perhaps this would help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf

Comment: The seminal resource for beta regression is *A Better Lemon Squeezer& by Smithson and Verkullen.